# Can you have 2 ranges in google script?

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script

I basically have all the classes on the same sheet and want to organise each class by first & last name.
Each class has 2 columns being used. It works when I use one sort range and sorts out the columns just need the rest of it now. Any help would be great as I am fairly new at all this.

```
SHEET_NAME = "ALL STUDENTS";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A3:B100";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 2, ascending: true},  // 3 = column number, sorting by descending order
{column: 1, ascending: false}, // 1 = column number, sort by ascending order 
];

function onEdit(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}

  SHEET_NAME = "ALL STUDENTS";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "D3:E100";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 5, ascending: true},  // 3 = column number, sorting by descending order
{column: 4, ascending: false}, // 1 = column number, sort by ascending order 
];

function onEdit(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All declarations outside of function are global to the entire project.  So all of your range declarations will result in the last declaration.  `SORT_DATA_RANGE = "D3:E100";`

If you want them to be unique to each function then you will have to put them in each function.  However, in your case you also must give each function in your project a different name.  So you cannot have two functions named onEdit().  You can create two installable onedit triggers and attach them to two different functions.

You also cannot have two multiSortColumns() functions.  You can give the multiSortColumns function a parameter and use the same function over again.

Note: this is basic JavaScript.  You might do well to do a little reading on your own.  I get a lot info from [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7)